# Pop up messages box are not displayed

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

I want after a user is registered a message showing that user is successful registered should display, the same for same for logout and login

The message is displayed, but it doesn't pop up I think the problem is on the script side. Please help!!

base.hmtl

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %} 
    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}, classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'info' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}, classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'warning' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}, classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'error' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}, classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `"` after the message template,
please try

```html
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %} 
    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}", classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'info' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}", classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'warning' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}", classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% elif message.tags == 'error' %}
     <script>M.toast({html: " {{message}}", classes:"blue rounded",displayLenght:2000});</script>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```